# How to fix The surrogate pair (0xD83D, 0x27) is invalid

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I have a byte array, the text is xml with "Hei ". I do

```
var bodyText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(transportMessage.Body);
var bodyXml = XElement.Parse(bodyText);
```

Get string encodes emoji to `&# xD83D;&#x DE0A;` so XElement.Parse throws:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.ArgumentException: The surrogate pair (0xD83D, 0x27) is invalid. A high surrogate character (0xD800 - 0xDBFF) must always be paired with a low surrogate character (0xDC00 - 0xDFFF).

How can I remove this emoji (or any other) I tried to use regex with invalid xml chars `[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]` but it doesn't match that emoji.

Comment: Are you getting unicode?  If so then use Encoding.Unicode (not UTF8).  If you are sending xml through html then you must encode and decode :  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode() and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()

Comment: no, it's not unicode. The rest of the message is encoded correctly, just the emoji is weird

Comment: `GetString` does NOT encode text, it decodes it. If `GetString` returns text containing `&#xD83D;&#xDE0A;` it must have already been encoded this way in the byte array. Can you show the contents of the byte array? And does the decoded string really contain the spaces (`&# xD83D;&#x DE0A;` instead of `&#xD83D;&#xDE0A;`)?

Comment: BTW: The numeric character references `&#xD83D;&#xDE0A;` are correct way to represent the emoji. However, it's unnecessary. Except in pathetic circumstances, XML is transmitted in UTF-8 or UTF-16, which support the full Unicode range. So there is no need to escape any characters except `<'&">`.

Comment: Surrogate pairs exist in utf16, not in utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to remove this:

```
 private static readonly Regex EmojiRegex = new Regex("&#x?[A-Fa-f0-9]+;");
 private static string ReplaceInvalidXmlCharacterReferences(string input)
        {
            if (input.IndexOf("&#") == -1)
                return input;

            return EmojiRegex.Replace(input, match =>
            {
                string ncr = match.Value;
                uint num;
                var frmt = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;

                bool isParsed =
                    ncr[2] == 'x' ?   // the x must be lowercase in XML documents
                    uint.TryParse(ncr.Substring(3, ncr.Length - 4), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, frmt, out num) :
                    uint.TryParse(ncr.Substring(2, ncr.Length - 3), NumberStyles.Integer, frmt, out num);

                return isParsed && !XmlConvert.IsXmlChar((char)num) ? "" : ncr;
            });
        }
```